# Uncaught ReferenceError: addFriend is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, opencart

I cannot get a javascript function to work when called through a html onClick call.  The calling code is

```
<tr data-name="buttons" style="border-top: #FFF 1px Solid;margin-top:10px">
                <td colspan="2"><a onClick="addFriend()" class="button"><?php echo $addFriend ?></a></td>
            </tr>
```

The function that is further down in the code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var emailFriend = 1;

    function addFriend(){
        var html  = '<tr id="friend' + emailFriend + '">';
            html += '   <td><?php echo $friendEmail ?></td>';
            html += '   <td>';
            html += '       <input type="text" name="emailFriend[' + emailFriend + ']" data-name="emailFriend" size="60" />';
            html += '       <a onClick="$(\'#friend' + emailFriend + '\').remove()" class="emailRemove"></a>';
            html += '   </td>';
            html += '</tr>'
        $('tr[data-name="buttons"]').before(html);
        emailFriend++;
    }</script>
```

However, when the button is clicked, no action is taken.  The Google Chrome console states Uncaught ReferenceError: addFriend is not defined.

I am thinking either a syntax error or I am missing something entirely.  Any ideas?

Comment: I would like to add that this is an extension on OpenCart, but the developer went silent...
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=14000&filter_search=refer%20a%20friend&filter_license=0&page=2

Comment: `<?php echo $friendEmail ?>` is this returning a name with a `'` in it? I couldn't find any problems with your JS. So I guess you need `htmlentities` on this.

Comment: whats the html output after php processing?

Comment: Try doing an inspect element on the page and finding the html of the script after the php has processed.

Comment: No, its grabbing from another language file. `($_['friendName']   = 'Name Friend:';)`

Comment: A live representation of the issue is on the following page.  Click on the "Get 10% off order..." to see the error 
http://hardtofindpartysupplies.com/Adventure-Time-Birthday-Party-Supplies/Adventure-Time-Large-Paper-Plates-lunch-dinner-finn-jake

Comment: Still if my name is `Kevin O'Leary` this will break your JS code if not escaped.

Comment: I am running an editor that (I BELEIVE) removes any "odd" characters from imputed text. http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have an error in your script before it ever parses the addFriend function, which is why it's not defined.  Test it by commenting everything out except this function, see if it works.  Then start adding pieces in until it crashes.  When it does you'll know where the actual problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the script block to the `<head>` section, so it's garanteed that this script will be loaded before the user can click a button.

Answer (score 0):

use a tool for example firebug and type **addFriend** not addFriend() to the console. then you will see type of this function. you may also invoke *typeof addFriend*. you should see function as output. 
the best is comment out all lines in the function definition, because wrong order or wrong paired ' may cause trouble in the js engine.